# How to replace window TKInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5

I would like the current window to be replaced with the contents instead of a new window opening up. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def adminLogin():
    global AnameEL
    global ApwordEL # More globals :D
    global ArootA

    ArootA = Tk() # This now makes a new window.
    ArootA.geometry('1280x720')
    ArootA.title('Admin login') # This makes the window title 'login'

    f1 = Frame(width=200, height=200, background="#D3D3D3")
    f2 = Frame(ArootA, width=400, height=200)

    f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
    f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

    AnameL = Label(f2, text='Username: ') # More labels
    ApwordL = Label(f2, text='Password: ') # ^
    AnameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    ApwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    AnameEL = Entry(f2) # The entry input
    ApwordEL = Entry(f2, show='*')
    AnameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    ApwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

    AloginB = Button(f2, text='Login', command=CheckAdmin) # This makes the login button, which will go to the CheckLogin def.
    AloginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

def CheckAdmin(): 
    if AnameEL.get() == "test" and ApwordEL.get() == "123" : # Checks to see if you entered the correct data.
        r = Tk() # Opens new window
        r.title('Sucess')
        loginC = Button(r, text='Add new login', command=Signup)
        loginC.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        r.mainloop()
    else:
        r = Tk()
        r.title('Error')
        r.geometry('550x450')
        rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
        rlbl.pack()
        r.mainloop()

def Signup(): # This is the signup definition, 
    global pwordE # These globals just make the variables global to the entire script, meaning any definition can use them
    global nameE
    global roots

    roots = Tk() # This creates the window, just a blank one.
    roots.title('Signup') # This renames the title of said window to 'signup'
    intruction = Label(roots, text='Please Enter new Credidentials\n') # This puts a label, so just a piece of text saying 'please enter blah'
    intruction.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E) # This just puts it in the window, on row 0, col 0. If you want to learn more look up a tkinter tutorial :)

    nameL = Label(roots, text='New Username: ') # This just does the same as above, instead with the text new username.
    pwordL = Label(roots, text='New Password: ') # ^^
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W) # Same thing as the instruction var just on different rows. :) Tkinter is like that.
    pwordL.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W) # ^^

    nameE = Entry(roots) # This now puts a text box waiting for input.
    pwordE = Entry(roots, show='*') # Same as above, yet 'show="*"' What this does is replace the text with *, like a password box :D
    nameE.grid(row=1, column=1) # You know what this does now :D
    pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1) # ^^

    signupButton = Button(roots, text='Signup', command=FSSignup) # This creates the button with the text 'signup', when you click it, the command 'fssignup' will run. which is the def
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    roots.mainloop() # This just makes the window keep open, we will destroy it soon

adminLogin()
```

As you can see at each button press a new windows is opened. I would like the current window to be replaced instead.As you can see at each button press a new windows is opened. I would like the current window to be replaced instead.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new window in CheckAdmin() destroy f1 then create a new frame inside of ArootA or change ArootA.

For example in the invalid case of CheckAdmin():

```
    f1.destroy() # Removes everything currently inside ArootA.
    ArootA.geometry('550x450')
    ArootA.title('Error')
    rlbl = Label(ArootA, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
    rlbl.pack()
```

Which also requires f1 to be a global. I also needed to add ArootA.mainloop() at the end of adminLogin() to get a window to open.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple windows because of the way your code is designed. You have three main routines: `adminLogin()`, `CheckAdmin()`, and `Signup()`. Each of those routines creates a new "root" or "master" window with a call to `Tk()`, and they do it each time they're called. Your application should only create a single master window -- one call to `Tk()`. And then you can pass that master window to each of your three functions. Or use it as a global.

You can also hide or remove widgets that you placed with `.grid()` by calling `.grid_forget()` or `.grid_remove()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gary!

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the code to replace current window, but i am not sure if that is what you ask for. pls try it out, it does replace the window for each function call, but still retain one root window.

```
#%%
from tkinter import *

def adminLogin():
    global AnameEL
    global ApwordEL # More globals :D
    global ArootA

    AnameL = Label(f2, text='Username: ') # More labels
    ApwordL = Label(f2, text='Password: ') # ^
    AnameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    ApwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    AnameEL = Entry(f2) # The entry input
    ApwordEL = Entry(f2, show='*')
    AnameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    ApwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

    AloginB = Button(f2, text='Login', command=CheckAdmin) # This makes the 
    login button, which will go to the CheckLogin def.
    AloginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)


 def CheckAdmin(): 
    if AnameEL.get() == "test" and ApwordEL.get() == "123" : # Checks to see 
    if you entered the correct data.
    f2.destroy()
    #r = Tk() # Opens new window
    loginL = Label(f3, text = 'Success!!!')
    loginC = Button(f3, text='Add new login', command=Signup)
    loginL.grid(row = 2, column=0, sticky=W)
    loginC.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=E)
    #r.mainloop()
else:
    f2.destroy()
    #r = Tk() # Opens new window
    loginL2 = Label(f3, text = 'Error!!')
    ribl = Label(f3, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
    loginL2.grid(row = 2, column=0, sticky=W)
    ribl.grid(row = 3, column=0, sticky=W)

    #.mainloop()


def Signup(): # This is the signup definition, 
    global pwordE # These globals just make the variables global to the 
    entire script, meaning any definition can use them
    global nameE
    global roots

    f3.destroy()
    #r = Tk() # Opens new window
    loginL3 = Label(f4, text = 'Signup!!!') # This renames the title of said 
    window to 'signup'
    loginL3.grid(row = 0, column=50, sticky=W)

    intruction = Label(f4, text='Please Enter new Credidentials\n') # This 
    puts a label, so just a piece of text saying 'please enter blah'
    intruction.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E) # This just puts it in the 
    window, on row 0, col 0. If you want to learn more look up a tkinter 
    tutorial :)

    nameL = Label(f4, text='New Username: ') # This just does the same as 
    above, instead with the text new username.
    pwordL = Label(f4, text='New Password: ') # ^^
    nameL.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W) # Same thing as the instruction 
    var just on different rows. :) Tkinter is like that.
    pwordL.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W) # ^^

    nameE = Entry(f4) # This now puts a text box waiting for input.
    pwordE = Entry(f4, show='*') # Same as above, yet 'show="*"' What this 
    does is replace the text with *, like a password box :D
    nameE.grid(row=3, column=1) # You know what this does now :D
    pwordE.grid(row=4, column=1) # ^^

    signupButton = Button(f4, text='Signup', command=FSSignup) # This 
    creates 
    the button with the text 'signup', when you click it, the command 
    'fssignup' 
    will run. which is the def
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    roots.mainloop() # This just makes the window keep open, we will 
    destroy it soon

    ArootA = Tk() # This now makes a new window.
    ArootA.geometry('1280x720')
    ArootA.title('Admin login') # This makes the window title 'login'

    f1 = Frame(width=200, height=200, background="#D3D3D3")
    f2 = Frame(ArootA, width=400, height=200)

    f2.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0, side = TOP)
    #f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)
    f3 = Frame(ArootA, width=550, height=450)
    f3.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0, side = TOP)
    f4 = Frame(ArootA, width=550, height=450)
    f4.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0, side = TOP)

    adminLogin()

    ArootA.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Grace thanks for the reply. There seems to be some indentation and comment not being on the same line errors. I assume u meant this? https://pastebin.com/raw/7CXb28Wd If so, I get these errors: "NameError: name 'f2' is not defined"

Comment: Hi qtt qtt The link you sent doesnt have the right version so i have re pasted the right one here. It works very fine without any error. https://pastebin.com/tYh9kz4J

Comment: Hi qtt qtt, check out the correct link version here https://pastebin.com/tYh9kz4J, the one you paste is not correct. This one works very fine without any errors